# How to use private app in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-workspace

For the last two days I'm stuck with publishing my private app... Steps i did:

1. Registered `GSuite` in my company domain.
2. Checked thousand of options by instructions from `Google Support`
3. Registered `Google Play Developer Account` in my company domain.
4. Published the app (also check the box to allow to use app only from my organization)

The main problem is that I cant find the app in the store by search. I can open it directly by the link like `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.app.id` but even then I get something that `Your admin doesn't let you to install it`.

Yes, I know that I need to add it to white list in `GSuite` but as I told before I cant find it through the search to be able to add it.

I already tried to contact `Google Support` in different ways (phone, email, chat) but all they doing are just redirecting me from one team to other.

Does any one have experience in using private google apps?

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, follow the next steps:

1. While signed in as the admin, go to https://play.google.com/work.
2. Find the app and approve it there. Note the appid from the app URL. For example, for the Gmail app
   (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm),
   the appid is "com.google.android.gm".
3. Visit the Admin console Android app management page: https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#MobileApplicationManagement:platform=android
4. Add the appid as parameter in URL, for example, if the appid is com.google.android.gm:
   https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#MobileApplicationManagement:platform=android&appId=com.google.android.gm
5. You will see a whitelist popup where you can choose the configuration.
6. Click 'whitelist'.